# Using matrix transformation produces a distorted results now

Tags: css, transform

After recent updates of webkit (tested in chrome and opera browsers) there is some kind of mess in how `transform: matrix` works. Take a look at [this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmQk6.jpg).

Previously the blue rectangle was perfectly aligned with black screen on the picture, but now there is some distortion. This change I have noticed just during last week or two, before that blue rectangle was aligned perfectly using the same matrix.

So my question is was some breaking changes were introduced? Any way to fix it?

Basically this blue rectangle is rendered on a page using matrix transformation in CSS, like:

```
transform: matrix3d(0.159713, -0.01934, 0, 6.2e-05, 0.046304, 0.222158, 0, 1e-06, 0, 0, 1, 0, 168.547, 118.847, 0, 1)
```

**EDIT:** Reproduced errors:

- tool [here](http://www.useragentman.com/matrix/#E4UwziAuBCCumQPYDsBMBeASuKACAYosALYBkAZsIsQAwAe6NFVtAno6UvegKxNfsAjABZhzaoKE1+iQQ0HTOs9sMWVqqeYqSb0wgByClqdgHZTSgMwNRANivtLNAJykAJoksARdJGCwQUgBLN0F0AGVYACNiIMhgtwxsCHiAC0hiABsAYRRIEGRIdAAeAAcAPgAVVKCwXFrcAENcKMzEAGMAa1wQTJBiAsgAOmKAegqAKFJ2sDBcwsH0UYAqCdxlghBe3Eot3CQetzim5FZcRHJ91JBcMEhWPrqo3sQAdyG15dGJiZWe5DAsFATUymSuN16-UGdTuDxAbhaL1euFgEBaRDcIGAAFooog6OtvkNWh1OgAaXAAYgA5sAQrgAN5rXAsvF0bFgIIALyCyGpAC50cBMTi2QBuCYAXx+f2qN0QUQAViB2pBEeQiDdjg0-I0ARqSPDCRNKbJGczWY0urTELBkG5BZTyOR2q72hLpb8NnLzkqVWrGuR8sB6mrUo0nltkPtgHqwAaBgivibEKhzSzLdaqHaHVS3e1nR6ZRtcsRiChbvdHjsiOiCQrlaqwENjcS2l10xmNYUOdyQILedc6ZAPbhi7hsuFwjWQ5BrrhafTkzS6QimRmWlbOjac4KgZkABQAIiCxEa1PAoyiW539qG1KC5CPAEpcKBSiBGmqwO0qKDcDQAG4K8NT5BKG7XEE1LpIK+jSKUdDgRmpSIJykBBCggqgJkX5BAAbiASEsogBHAOQbSvIKNRuJiyBFgklgRNEsRqgAEpUACyAAyJwIpO4QJMI6DZHq7S9AkPDoO0bQQAkthSTJIBAA) produces incorrect result (you can see how much pivot circles are away from actual transformed rectangle corners), but in Internet explorer it works fine
- results in [this](http://franklinta.com/2014/09/08/computing-css-matrix3d-transforms/) article
- effect is observable in [this article](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/c02ccf25704d434cebd1) as well

**ALSO**
Here's an example of matrixes

```
Internet Explorer
matrix3d(0.216413, -0.026219, 0, 6.2e-005, 0.062742, 0.301178, 0, 1e-006, 0, 0, 1, 0, 228.383, 161.12, 0, 1)

Chrome/Opera
matrix3d(0.216413, -0.026219, 0, 6.2e-05, 0.062742, 0.301178, 0, 1e-06, 0, 0, 1, 0, 228.383, 161.12, 0, 1)
```

They are identical, but in IE blue rectangle is transformed and displayed [correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEjrw.jpg), and in Chrome/Opera is [distorted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmQk6.jpg) just like on picture linked in the beginning of this post.